# How can i set selected pins for PORTC in ATmega328P as inputs in AVR assembly code?

Tags: assembly, avr

I'm trying to code in all PORTD as inputs for 8 bit switch, and all PORTB as output for LEDs, and then code PINC 0 and 1 as inputs for a selector that makes the 4 MSBs of PORTD do arithmetic operations to the 4 LSBs based on the input for the C1 and C0 pins, such as Addition when C1C0 are 00 and subtraction when its 01... and so on. I know how to set PORTD and PORTB as inputs and outputs but i don't know how to set an individual PIN of a PORT as input when i'm not going to be needing the rest of the ports.

```
LDI R16, 0x00 
OUT PORTD, R16
LDI R17, 0xFF
OUT PORTB, R17

;that way i set those two ports as inputs and outputs for the switch and led
;but i want to make PINC, 0 AND PINC, 1 as inputs two for a selector in AVR assembly, how?
```

Comment: You can configure data direction individually for each bit in port by writing to corresponding DDRx register. Read [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf) for your MCU. You can manipulate bits individually with logic instructions (they all are listed in the datasheet). Are you asking for examples of AVR logic instructions usage?

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong, your code didn't set PORTB as output at all. The direction of data transfer is set using the DDRx registers. After power up, this registers are reset to zero. This means that all pins of the ports are input. The correct way to set it up is this:

```
LDI R16, 0x00 
OUT DDRD, R16  ;it is not necessary - it is the default state after reset
LDI R17, 0xFF
OUT DDRB, R17  ;whole PORTB is now configured as output for LED
; PORTC is still whole setup as input because it is default state after reset
LDI R16, 0x00 
OUT DDRC, R16  ;of course you can set up DDRC in same way as DDRD

;example of mixed setting for port B
LDI R16, 0xFC  ;0b11111100
OUT DDRB, R16  ;now PB0 and PB1 are inputs. PB2 up to PB7 are outputs
```

Read chapter [13.2.3 Switching Between Input and Output](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf#page=60)
and
[13.4 Register Description](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf#page=72)
in the DS

Comment: okay, i understand. setting those two ports as inputs and outputs iS correct. but when i said something like, making only pin c0 and pin c1 as inputs too. i meant the assembly code as this:  CBI DDRC, 0     ; this is for pinc 0